# How can I select date dynamically from calendar in input text field in BMC site form?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, date

I am using Pyautogui to navigate through form fields on pop up window in an ITSM website.

All fields are done but now have to select date from a field which is of Input = text, InputType = DateOnly.

Please note selenium web driver is not an option here since I am not able to switch to the frame of pop up window which opens in middle of the process where date field is to be filled.

Please suggest possible solution to implement in Python. Preferably, selecting date using JS through Python using JS2PY

```
import js2py


javascript_code = """
function selectDate(dateString) {
  var dateInput = document.getElementById('datepicker');
  dateInput.value = dateString;
}
selectDate('2023-06-08');
"""

# Evaluate the JavaScript code in the JavaScript context
select = context.js2py.evaljs.execute(javascript_code)
select()
```

Comment: This is not possible, you will need Selenium or some browser automation framework since JS2Py alone does not interact with the HTML on the webpage.